# Can I benefit from Intel Rapid Storage Technology Somehow with this setup?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, intel-rst

I have laptop Msi GV62 7RD with 2 disks.

SSD
1x M.2 x2

&&

HDD
1x 2.5" SATA HDD

[image]

So basicly `1TB HDD Sata + 128GB M.2 SSD`

[image]

My operating system (Windows 10 Pro) is installed on the M.2 SSD drive.

And I have Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

And the question is; Can I somehow benefit from this application/technology with this setup?

Do I benefit from this somehow right now?

Can I do something to get more from this technology?

Comment: Intel RST is basically RAID.  You don't have enough disks of the same capacity to use Intel RST

Comment: Apparently Intel Rapid Storage Technology has a feature called "Dynamic Storage Accelerator"  according to: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html it does: "Dynamic storage accelerator accelerates the performance of your SSD by dynamically adjusting system power management policies to deliver up to 15 percent faster performance during heavy multitasking compared to default power management." I'm not sure if this applies to M.2 or is really helpful, so I'm not gonna post it as an answer but add it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intel Rapid Storage Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Rapid_Storage_Technology)
is not applicable to your case.

It is mostly useful in RAID configurations, which is not counseled in your case
where there is a large difference in the size of the disks.

In your case, its only use would be to use the SSD as a non-volatile intelligent
caching for the HDD. Moving frequently accessed data over to the cache is said
to improve overall system performance, but there exist no benchmarks to justify
the claim.

Since you are not minded to move Windows to the HDD and use the SSD as
cache mechanism that is solely controlled by the Intel software,
and which might or might not improve performance but at the lose of 128 GB
of SSD storage, it is not useful to you.